# Where to store and how to access a connection string

Tags: c#, connection-string

Where to add the connection string in a `C#` project? Like this string?

```xml
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="strConn" 
         connectionString="Data Source=abc;Password=pass;User ID=user" 
         providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client">
    </add>
</connectionStrings>
```

And how can I call it from my `program.cs` file?

Comment: What kind of project: ASP.NET? Winforms? WPF? SIlverlight? COnsole app??

Comment: @marc_s - Its a console app. And i dont see any app.config file in my project?

Comment: My crystal ball foresaw that this was a console app.

Comment: I just selected the XML and hit the 'code' button. What XML was missing then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be added in the configuration file.  If it is an ASP.NET application, then this would be the `web.config` file.  If it is a Winforms/Console application this would be the `app.config` file.

To call it from the application, you'd have to use the `System.Configuration` namespace like so:

```
using System.Configuration;

string YourConnectionString = 
    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["yourConnStringName"].ConnectionString;
```

Where `"yourConnStringName"` is the name of your `connectionString` in your config file.

Comment: I have console app. But i dont see any app.config file in the project? Do i need to add it?

Comment: Yes, you need to add that.  Add items and you'll see configuration file.

Answer (score 2):

The connection string like the one you posted is placed in a configuration file called `app.config` and whenever you want to get a connectionstring you can get it like:

```
string strConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["strConn"].ConnectionString;
```

see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.connectionstrings.aspx)

Comment: The connection string COULD be stored in appSettings, but the OP seems to want to use the `connectionStrings` section.

Answer (score 0):

Add it to your app.config under `<configuration>` and to call it from your program.cs use:

```
ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["strConn"]
```